# Perfect forwarding and std::tuple (or other templated class)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, perfect-forwarding

I have some difficulties with perfect forwarding.

Here is my current level of understanding : glue Template + rvalue reference + std::forward and a special magical mode get activated where template deduction rules have not the same meaning as usual, but are crafted to allow perfect forwarding. Example :

```
template <typename T>
void outer(T&& t)
{
   inner(std::forward<T>(t)); // perfect forwarding activated
}
```

But what happen if T is actually a templated class ?
For example, how can I perfect forward a std::tuple ? If use a T&& as aboce I will lost all type information of the objects contained in the tuple.
However the following code can't work :

```
template <typename... Args>
void outer(std::tuple<Args...>&& t) 
{
   inner(std::forward<std::tuple<Args...>>(t));
   use_args_types_for_something_else<Args...>(); // I need to have Args available
}

int main()
{
   std::tuple<int, double, float> t(4, 5.0, 4.0f);
   outer(t);
}
```

Last gcc snapshot says :

```
error: cannot bind 'std::tuple<int, double, float> lvalue to
std::tuple<int, double, float>&&
```

So clearly, we are still in the general, non-template case where lvalue can't bind to rvalue reference. "Perfect forwading mode" is not activated

So I tried to be sneaky and pass my tuple as a template template :

```
template <
  typename... Args
  template <typename...> class T
>
void outer(T<Args...>&& t) 
{
   inner(std::forward<T<Args...>>(t));
   use_args_type_for_something_else<Args...>(); 
}
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: Can't you just call std::forward without specifying the type (since it's a template function and can use deduction)? `std::forward(t)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfect forwarding works only if the type of the parameter is a template type for the function, so the only way to achieve perfect forwarding is like in your first example:

```
template <typename T>
void outer(T&& t)
{
   inner(std::forward<T>(t)); // perfect forwarding activated
}
```

The above works because it is a special case where `T` is deduced as `SomeType&` or `SomeType&&`.

This, however, does not mean that the type information for the tuple elements is lost for good. It is still retrievable (although I don't think you can typedef a variadic template pack). For example, you can still call `use_args_types_for_something_else` like this:

```
template <class T>
struct call_uses_args;

template <class ...Args>
struct call_uses_args<std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    void call() const { use_args_types_for_something_else<Args...>(); }
};

template <typename TupleT>
void outer(TupleT&& t)
{
   inner(std::forward<TupleT>(t));
   call_uses_args<typename std::remove_reference<TupleT>::type>().call();
}
```

There might be no good general solution, though, but hopefully such situations are rare. (E.g, in this particular example, it might be simpler just to overload `outer`.)

Comment: Thanks for your nice and precise answer. So regarding perfect forwarding in c++11, I still feel a bit disturbing that it rely so much on this strange combo "template + rref + std::forward". It creates a tiny spot where general rules (like "rvalue references ONLY bind to rvalue") don't apply anymore. I wonder if some special syntax for perfect forwarding would not have been better for c++11. Anyways, it's true that a workaround in this case is not that big of a deal as it's still possible to make two overload for `outer`, one with const ref and one with rref to emulate PF.